# ASP.NET "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to debug this issue but I'm not really sure what was the issue.

When I log in as an admin, I am unable to do this function - change password. It kept prompting this error~

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Admin' does not contain a definition for 'ConfirmPass' and no accessible extension method 'ConfirmPass' accepting a first argument of type 'Admin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Line 51:  Confirm password
> Line 52:  
> Line 53:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Confirm password", @type = "password" } })
> Line 54:  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like your user 'Admin' data model doesn't have a ConfirmPass field. Maybe it's a different data model for Admin role. Check this out !